# Session Expired when WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) are different

Tags: directory, cookies, site-url

I followed this article to allow me to put our company's WordPress blog on a subdirectory of our Heroku hosted site:

http://nicolasmlv.com/wordpress-in-your-rails-app/

This says to add this code to wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','https://www.yourcoolapp.com/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://blog-yourcoolapp.rhcloud.com');
```

Everything worked great except when I try to go to Appearance > Customize it asks me to log in again (even-though I'm already logged in). I presume this is some sort of cross domain cookie issue. I have third party cookies enabled in chrome, so not sure how to resolve.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Aaron